Making div always take the whole height of page - with negative top margin
On my page I've got that one section that I want to always take the whole height of the page and overflow the navbar and the footer. I moved the div with negative margin to the top but I cannot make it extend to the bottom. This is static website so needs to be done with SCSS only. Can someone help?


.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.full-height {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
  margin-top: -4rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.normal-column {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}
<div class="nav">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-height">
  </div>
  <div class="normal-column">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>




Curious... how does this being a "static" website preclude the use of JavaScript? Scripts are also (usually) static.

Have you tried using  height: 110vh  basically here you set the height larger than the viewport that way it might overflow to the footer as well

You need to increase the height by adding the height of the nav and footer - height: calc(100% + 10rem);


.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.full-height {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
  margin-top: -4rem;
  height: calc(100% + 10rem);
  width: 200px;
}

.normal-column {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}
<div class="nav">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-height">
  </div>
  <div class="normal-column">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>




Set both top and bottom margin using negative value (that you can combine with margin-block). Don't use height: 100%, the default stretch alignment will do the job for you.


.nav {
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}
.container {
  height: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.full-height {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
  margin-block: -4rem -6rem; /* HERE */
  width: 200px;
}

.normal-column {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
  width: 200px;
}
.footer {
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-height">
  </div>
  <div class="normal-column">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>




It's a bit fragile (any layout with hard-coded sizing is), but you can simply add the height of the header and footer to the height of the full-height element.
One way to make it a bit less fragile is to use custom properties (variables) for all common values. This prevents changes in rules for one element from breaking the layout.


:root {
  --header-height: 4rem;
  --footer-height: 6rem;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.full-height {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .5;
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--header-height));
  height: calc(100% + var(--header-height) + var(--footer-height));
  width: 200px;
}

.normal-column {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--footer-height);
  background-color: #FFE2E2;
}
<div class="nav"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="full-height"></div>
  <div class="normal-column"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>




https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

